# Implement surface imperfection textures over base material textures

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm running into a little roadblock when it comes to implementing surface imperfections on my object.

The following are the texture files I have for my initial material:

[image]

Using google and some video tutorials I was able to setup the following material using these textures:

[image]

Marble material on Suzanne:

[image]

Now, I also have texture files for some large cracks to use as surface imperfections:

[image]

My initial instinct was to implement this as a second material, and then I would be able to apply both materials to the same object via some sort of layering system.

[image]

However, from what I can tell it looks like you can only have a single material assigned to a given face of an object in blender.

Assuming that is the case, how could I best go about implementing this second batch of textures into my initial material to act as surface imperfections? Or if I'm mistaken and two separate materials is the way to go, how do I go about utilizing both of them in this case?

Any additional insight/advice/pointers are welcome. I'm sure there's more than one way to go about implementing something like this.

Comment: Hello, yes you can assign only one material per face. You need to tell what you want to do exactly with this second material, if what intersests you is the bump map then use it in your first material, plug it into a Vector > Bump Map node that you plug into the Normal input of the Principled BSDF. If you want a 50/50 mix between the 2 materials, then use a Mix Shader and plug the 2 Principled BSDF into the 2 inputs of this node. If some parts display one material and the others display the other one, use a b&w mask as factor in the Mix Shader, etc

Comment: As @moonboots says, you need to tell Blender how to consume the two texture sets within one material. You could use the large cracks opacity map as the factor for the mix nodes.

Answer (score 3):

You're really close to what you aim for.
Instead of having two materials, the usual way to add imperfections is to **combine two shaders**.

In the example blow, I use a B&W image of scratches to create a shader with only some bumps.
The second image is the base marble shader.
The last one uses the B&W image of the scratches as a mask between the two shaders:

[image]

[image]

[image]