# How to make scratches on shinny plastic material

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have made a transparent material (the four window rectangles), and lowered its blend mode. I import a PNG scratch texture I made, Images as planes, and I want to make those scratches seem they are on the windows, like the examples I have attached.

Also here's the file
and scratches link

[image]

https://ibb.co/sCKhBd6

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have opaque faces behind your glasses, you need to delete them if you want to see through. For the glass material, under *Settings* enable *Screen Space Refraction* and in the *Render panel > Screen Space Reflections*, enable *Refraction*. For your basic glass material plug your *Image Texture* into the *Transmission* of your *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The scratch texture can be used as :

- an input for the Bump node to create dents
- a mapping to increase the roughness of the plastic
- a mapping to reduce the transparency of the plastic

in order to try to achieve the effect you're looking for.

Similar topic here for node setup if needed :
[Implement surface imperfection textures over base material textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/300252/implement-surface-imperfection-textures-over-base-material-textures)

Comment: Both answers super helpful, Ill be posting another inquiry I have regarding materials.
Kind regards.